# What is the probability that the game is in the player's favour?

Tags: probability

I think I even did not understand what the question is asking!

A player tosses an unfair coin twice and wins if the two flips are different. Suppose the chance the coin turns up tails is $q$, which is randomly drawn from $[0,1]$. What is the probability that the game is in the player's favour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 mutually inclusive outcomes that say you win: "HT" and "TH".

The probability for the first ("HT") is $(1-q)q$, because that is the prodcuct of the probability that the first toss comes up as $H, (=1-q)$ and the second coin comes up as $T, (=q)$. Since the tosses are independent (not explicitely stated, but the "general assumption" for coin tosses), the probability for both happening is the product of the individual probabilities.

Similiarly, the probability of "TH" coming up is $q(1-q)=(1-q)q$.

Since "HT" and "TH" are exclusive events (they can't both happen), the probability that either happens is the sum of the indivisual probabilities:

$$P(\text{"You win"})=(1-q)q+q(1-q)=2q(1-q).$$

Now the question is: When does this probability indicate the game is "in your favour"? Without any information on what your pay-in and pay-out are, the standard assumption is that they are the same, so you need to find out when

$$P(\text{"You win"})=2q(1-q) > 0.5.$$

Now, you can "complete the square" on  term that describes your probability:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
2q(1-q) & = & -2q^2+2q = -2(q^2-q)=-2(q^2-q+\frac14)-(-2)\frac14 \\
& = & -2(q-\frac12)^2+\frac12  =  0.5-2(q-0.5)^2\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

As can be seen from the last forumula, we have $0.5-2(q-0.5)^2 \le 0.5$ for all possible $q$, as the square subtracted from $0.5$ is always non-negative.

That means the game is **never** in favour for you, so the probability is $0$, regardless of how $q$ is distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you remove the fact that $q$ is itself a random variable. Suppose you know the bias of the coin ($q$ is fixed). Then the probability that two tosses give two different outcomes is

$$P_1(q) = 2q(1-q)$$

Now, for each $q$ in $[0,1]$, this is the probability of winning the game. Now you need to add up all the cases of winning over the entire spectrum to get the full probability. Since $q$ is uniformly distributed in [0,1],we can say that

$$\text{pdf}(q) = 1$$
$$P(q=q) = \text{pdf}(q)dq = dq$$

$$\implies P = \int_0^12q(1-q)dq = 1 - \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: why we should multiply by 2 in $P_{1}(q)$ ? isn't just 2 independent probability? so $P_{1}(q)=q(1-q)$?

Comment: Well either you get TH or HT - so $P(TH) = q(1-q)$ and $P(HT) = (1-q)(q)$

Comment: wait, it is multi choice question the answers are: 0, 1/2,1/8,1/20,3/4

Comment: When they say 'randomly drawn' I'm assuming it's uniform in [0,1].. maybe the question implies something else

Comment: like what? I am confused

Comment: While the answer is correct in what it calculates, it doesn't answer the question of OP. The question isn't to calculate the overall expected win probabilty for one instance of the game. It asks, pertaining to the distribution of $q$, what the probability is that the game is in the player's favor.